# Apache Reverse Proxy - Java application

Tags: java, apache, proxy, httprequest, reverse-proxy

We are currently running an Apache Reverse Proxy (forward only) without authentication, for a Java application in a back-end server. This will be the way is working:

Internet<--->Apache Reverse Proxy<---->Java Application Server

URL for client access from internet: example.com/java-app

The access to the Java application through the proxy is working fine, we can browse in the application and use it without any problem or bug.

My problem:

The Java application is making some requests internally to fetch some data from an external website, in this case, is fetching keys from a public PGP server, but the Java application receives a 404 error. The Java application is using a regular GET java.net.HttpURLConnection to the URL

```
http://pgp.uni-mainz.de/pks/lookup?search=%3Cusername@example.com%3E&op=index&options=mr&exact=on.
```

After checking the logs, apparently our proxy server is considering that external URL (http://pgp.uni-mainz.de) as local, cause I found this in the logs:

```
AH02417: Replacing host header 'pgp.uni-mainz.de' with host 'pgp.uni-mainz.de' given in the request uri
AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
AH00128: File does not exist: /var/www/pks/lookup
```

And after running wireshark in the proxy server I confirm that my apache proxy is not sending that request ouside, cause I found this

```
1528378541.404289000|192.x.x.x|54641|192.x.x.x|80|HTTP/1.1|GET|pgp.uni-mainz.de|http://pgp.uni-mainz.de/pks/lookup?search=%3Cusername@example.com%3E&op=index&options=mr&exact=on|Java/1.8.0_162|||||

1528378541.405104000|192.x.x.x|80|192.x.x.x|54641|HTTP/1.1|||||404|text/html; charset=iso-8859-1|290||
```

Just mention, that I could curl / wget the URL successfully from the backend server where the Java application is running and from the server where the Apache Proxy server is running.

```
http://pgp.uni-mainz.de/pks/lookup?search=%3Cusername@example.com%3E&op=index&options=mr&exact=on
```

Here is my proxy configuration for that site, that as you may see, is really simple and strait forward, and for the access to the java application is working fine:

```
SSLProxyVerify none
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyVia Off

<Proxy *>
        Require all granted
</Proxy>

ProxyPreserveHost On
AllowEncodedSlashes On
ProxyRequests Off

ProxyPass /synchrony http://backend-server.example.com:8091/synchrony

<Location /synchrony>
        Require all granted
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} Upgrade$ [NC]
        RewriteRule .* ws://backend-server.example.com:8091%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
</Location>

ProxyPass /java-app https://backend-server.example.com:8093/java-app nocanon
ProxyPassReverse /java-app https://backend-server.example.com:8093/java-app

<Location /java-app/>
        Require all granted
</Location>
```

The Java application is started with some parameters to let it know that is running behind a proxy, and others functionalities of this java application are working fine without any issue. This will be the Java configuration:

```
JVM_SUPPORT_RECOMMENDED_ARGS="-Dhttp.proxyHost=example.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=80 -Dhttps.proxyHost=example.com -Dhttps.proxyPort=443 -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=\"backend-server.example.com|localhost|127.0.0.1|192.x.x.x|proxy-server.example.com|*java-app\""
```

I tried to modify the proxy configuration, like the ProxyPreserveHost but I did not success. Where could be the problem?

Thanks a lot.